# Erro 102 em OpenQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou com este erro:

> Sintaxe incorreta próxima a '@SQL_LINKED'.. Error 102. SQLSTATE 42000.
>   Severity 15. MsgState 1. Line 78.

**Ao tentar executar esse script :**

```
 SET @SQL_LINKED = 'SELECT CAST(v.produto AS VARCHAR(20))   AS CAIXA,
 v.formula                      AS FORMULA,       
 coalesce(v.COMP_B,0)           AS CHB01,        
 coalesce(v.COMP_C,0)           AS CHC01,        
 coalesce(v.COMP_BC,0)          AS CHBC01,        
 coalesce(v.COMP_E,0)           AS CHE01,
 coalesce(v.COMP_BB,0)          AS CHBB01,        
 coalesce(v.COMP_BE,0)          AS CHBE01,        
 coalesce(v.COMP_AC,0)          AS CHAC01,        
 coalesce(v.COMP_EC,0)          AS CHEC01, 
 coalesce(v.COMP_A,0)           AS CHA01,        
 coalesce(v.COMP_D,0)           AS CHD01,        
 coalesce(v.COMP_DC,0)          AS CHDC01     
 FROM produtos_calc_l v 
 WHERE v.produto = '''''+@CodCai+''''' 
 AND v.formula NOT LIKE ''%D%'''  
 INSERT INTO ##tempvincos (codref, C, A, B,D, caixa, formula, chb01, chc01, 
 chbc01, che01, chbb01, chbe01, chac01, chec01, cha01, chd01, chdc01 )
 SELECT @CODREF, @ALTURA,  @COMPRIM,  @LARGURA, 0,   Vinco.* FROM   (SELECT 
 *  FROM   Openquery("server", @SQL_LINKED) ) AS Vinco
```

Como devo passar o *@SQL_LINKED* para o *OpenQuery* ?

Comment: Como está declarada a variável @CodCai? // Como está declarada a coluna v.produto?

Comment: Está declarada como `Declare @codcai varchar(20)`.

Comment: E como está declarada a coluna `v.produto`?

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Tente colocar `DECLARE @SQL_LINKED VARCHAR(7000)` antes de `SET @SQL_LINKED =`

Ficando Assim : `DECLARE @SQL_LINKED VARCHAR(7000) SET @SQL_LINKED =`

Faltou você declarar a sua variável local `@SQL_LINKED`, no seu código você apenas atribuiu um valor a ela, mas sem especificar o tipo dela.

Veja o seguinte link :

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql

Comment: Eu já declarei, só postei o trecho que está com problema.

Answer (score 0):

Excesso de apóstrofos na cláusula WHERE.

Se as coluna v.produto também está declarada como *string*, substitua

```
WHERE v.produto = '''''+@CodCai+'''''
```

por

```
WHERE v.produto = ''' + @CodCai + '''
```

---

Sugiro que primeiro teste a montagem do conteúdo da variável @SQL_LINKED. Faça algo como

```
-- código #1
SET @SQL_LINKED = 'SELECT CAST(v.produto AS VARCHAR(20))   AS CAIXA,
 v.formula                      AS FORMULA,       
 ...
 WHERE v.produto = ''' + @CodCai + '''
 AND v.formula NOT LIKE ''%D%'';';

PRINT @SQL_LINKED;
```

Quando tiver certeza de que o comando está sendo montado corretamente, avalie se a execução remota está correta:

```
-- código #2
SET @SQL_LINKED = 'SELECT CAST(v.produto AS VARCHAR(20))   AS CAIXA,
     v.formula                      AS FORMULA,       
     ...
     WHERE v.produto = ''' + @CodCai + '''
     AND v.formula NOT LIKE ''%D%'';';

SELECT top (10) Vinco.*
  from Openquery("INFOBOX", @SQL_LINKED) as Vinco;
```